# how do i save float value 1.00 it gives me out put like 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

i am saving the float value in my application. I want to save save the float value like 1.00
i tried it so long  but am getting the out put like 1.0 please give the solution

Comment: u can display it in 2 decimal with `"%.2f" % round(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two signs precision only for DISPLAY numbers in your application, you can create helper method in `ApplicationHelper` like this:

```
def printable_price(number, precision=2)
  number_with_precision(number, precision: precision)
end
```

And then in the views you can use:

```
printable_price(123)
```

It should be displayed `123.00`.

More about `number_with_precision` helper method you can read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a method in your model which is named like your attribute in the database like:

```
def price
   "$%.2f" % self[:price]
end
```

which gives you full control over the formatting or use the Rails provided helper method

```
def price
   ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(self[:price])
end
```

Hope it helps!